# Spark SQL Join error on cassandra UUID types

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, datastax-enterprise

I am just testing SQL stuff on Spark and i got this weird error when I join two tables by their ids (UUID).
Does anybody know any clue why this test doesn't work?. It seems to me it's Scala problem converting UUID types. anyway, any comments are welcomed!!

```
[root@spark2 ~]# dse spark
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.4.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Creating SparkContext...
Initializing SparkContext with MASTER: spark://1.2.3.4:7077
Created spark context..
Spark context available as sc.
Hive context available as hc.
CassandraSQLContext available as csc.

scala> val results = csc.sql("select h.id, h.program,s.flux from has.header h join has.s1d_flux s on h.id=s.id").cache();
results: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: uuid, program: string, flux: string]

scala> results.take(1).foreach(println);
[Stage 0:>                (0 + 11) / 11][Stage 1:>               (0 + 1) / 2620]WARN  2015-11-21 12:01:26 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 161.72.45.76): scala.MatchError: UUIDType (of class org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.types.UUIDType$)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlSerializer2$$anonfun$createSerializationFunction$1.apply(SparkSqlSerializer2.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlSerializer2$$anonfun$createSerializationFunction$1.apply(SparkSqlSerializer2.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Serializer2SerializationStream.writeKey(SparkSqlSerializer2.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(BlockObjectWriter.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.WritablePartitionedIterator$$anon$3.writeNext(WritablePartitionedPairCollection.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.spillToPartitionFiles(ExternalSorter.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[Stage 0:>
```

Comment: May be it's connected with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10501

Comment: @jguerra, have you fixed this issue if so could you post a workaround?